# String Length Not Equal To String Data Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got a strange problem in here.
I have two string to compare.

Lets call it :

**String "A" and String "B".**

Both of string have a same data

**"A" : "1234" and "B" : "1234"**

But when compare they didn't *same or not equal*.

I have try to **trim** both of string. But the result still not equal.

Then i try to check the string length.

**"A" contain 4, but "B" contain 16.**

So it is mean that

**string "A" has length 4 and string "B" has length 16.**

How it can be like this ?

So now i cannot compare it.

For note. **String "B"** data is a decrypt data from database. But the length became 16.

How i can solve this ? or return string "B" to normal.

Thank You

Edit :

I put the screenshot try see this

[image]

**And this is the code i use :**

```
if (Input_PIN.text.Length >= 4)
        {
            Debug.Log("A Text : " + Input_PIN.text);
            Debug.Log("A Lenght : " + Input_PIN.text.Length);
            Debug.Log("B Text : " + user_account_detail.Pin);
            Debug.Log("B Lenght : " + user_account_detail.Pin.Length);

            if (Input_PIN.text.Trim() == user_account_detail.Pin.Trim())
            {
                UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("scene_foundation");
            }
            else
            {
                UtilityScript.GetComponent<utility>().MessageBox_Pin_Wrong();
                Input_PIN.text = "";
            }

        }
```

**And this is the decrpyt code i use for string "B" :**

```
public static string Decrypt(string prm_text_to_decrypt, string prm_key, string prm_iv)
    {

        var sEncryptedString = prm_text_to_decrypt;

        var rj = new RijndaelManaged()
        {
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            KeySize = 256,
            BlockSize = 128,
        };

        var key = Convert.FromBase64String(prm_key);
        var IV = Convert.FromBase64String(prm_iv);

        var decryptor = rj.CreateDecryptor(key, IV);

        var sEncrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(sEncryptedString);

        var fromEncrypt = new byte[sEncrypted.Length];

        var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(sEncrypted);
        var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        csDecrypt.Read(fromEncrypt, 0, fromEncrypt.Length);

        return (Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fromEncrypt));
    }
```

Comment: There is only one explanation, they don't have the same data, this is only your assumption, prove it to your self by debugging it

Comment: @MichaelRandall yes i use debug.log and the result was same "1234" and "1234"

Comment: Is this because the decryption data ? I even debug.log both of data before compare them.. But the result was same. But the length didn't same

Comment: @MichaelRandall check that screenshot. That's the two data compare. And that's i debug.log before compare.

Comment: Clearly they aren't the same, because the length of A is 4 and the length of B is 16.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli so how to return the length from string "B" to exactly same with data ? the string "B" data only 4 digit like the screenshot shown. But the length is not correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is you have misread an array of byte and ended up with *Null Characters* `'\0'` at the end of a string.

```
var pin1 = Input_PIN.text.Trim('\0');
var pin2 = user_account_detail.Pin.Trim('\0');
```

**Update**

> That's correct. I trim with ('\0') and it is worked now. But why i
>   need to put ('\0') in trim ?

Because `Trim()` doesn't deal with null characters, you have to specify them explicitly

However, the design problem is why you have them in the first place

Comment: That's correct. I trim with ('\0') and it is worked now. But why i need to put ('\0') in trim ?